# Retrieve a users GPS coordinates over a website

Tags: android, ios, web, gps

So I want to create a website for internal company use that allows a user to fill in a survey on a mobile device and upon submitting the survey, their GPS location is also submitted.

Is this possible to do? If so can anyone recommend the software to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a Android App from your tag. You would want to pull the GPS location through a single update. Pass that to the webview through the URL parameters and then pass those along through the form submit.

If you are using just a webpage opened by a mobile browser on a phone I would suggest looking into HTML5 which has some handy resources. This however will only work on the more modren browsers and is not a 100% pinpoint location.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Sounds like you want the HTML5 solution.

Comment: That did it, thanks (:
I was trying to do it from the http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html#divingin before making the post but it wasn't clear enough how to implement it ^___^